# Arduino ESP8266 Socket.io Issue

Tags: socket.io, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I want to make a WebSocket inner ESP8266 but i cant do it.
I used this link for made it.
https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client
I get error inner SocketIOClient.h

The error is:

> In file included from C:\Users\WaffenSS\Desktop\ses\ses.ino:1:0:
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:44:2: error:
>   "Please specify an interface such as W5100, ENC28J60, or ESP8266"
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:45:2: error:
>   "above your includes like so : #define ESP8266 "
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

There is anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO is an API for WebSockets and most of Websocket libraries are supporting it.

I am pretty happy with this most contributed [Arduino WebSocket library](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets) and it also supports Socket.IO. Here is your [Socket.IO example](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/529a86cc26cff78896f6627bd9475d6060a36df5/examples/WebSocketClientSocketIO/WebSocketClientSocketIO.ino).

Here is a heartbeat message type of socket.io implementaiton from the example:

```
if((now - heartbeatTimestamp) > HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL) {
    heartbeatTimestamp = now;
    // socket.io heartbeat message
    webSocket.sendTXT("2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

into library you need set type of device that you use, C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\SocketIOClient/SocketIOClient.h:  open this file and uncomment any line where specified type of device